# Retrieve Plotly brush limits in Django environment

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-views, plotly

First of all I would like to say I have very few experience in Django and plotly, so excuse me if I may be asking something which makes no sense or has very few meaning.

In Django enviroment I know that programming logic takes place in the "Views.py" file, and all variables set on this file can be transfered to the "template.html" file and use them inside double curly braces "{{ VariableFromView }}".

I was wondering if there is any way, once the plot is created, to retrieve the limits of the displayed area in the plotly plot, either on the "view.py" or "template.py" files, and save them in a variable which could be used in the "template.html" file, such as:

***Variable definition example:***
xbrush = [plotly.xmin, plotly.xmax]
ybrush = [plotly.ymin, plotly.ymax]

***Variable call in template***
{{ xbrush }}
{{ ybrush }}

In my case I amb using Python code for the "Views.py" and Javascript and html for the "templates.html" file (as well as a little bit of Django template language for dealing with variables)

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve the same. I would suggest you to go through [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) once again to get better understanding of template context and [variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#variables). Since you already have variables xbrush and ybrush in your views.py, just make sure you return these in the context of your response. Like `render('template.html', {'xbrush':xbrush, 'ybrush': ybrush})`.Now in your template.html you can access these values using `{{ xbrush }}`. So now all you need now is create a script tag in your html file and now you can assign these values to javascript variables like `var xbrush = {{ xbrush }}`

Comment: Thanks Tarun!
I know how to define it in the Views.py interface, but what I want is to be able to automatically modify the values from xbrush and ybrush once the user interacts with the plotly plot... 
Plotly plots appear with a menu in the top right part which allows to zoom and make other options. I would like my variables to modify automatically once the user "plays" with the plotly plot...

Comment: In that case, you must handle the variables in client end only. If user changes those variables, you can either send a ajax request to server with new values which can be used for other process or you can use those variables and append them to url as GET params and then make use of them accordingly. The variables wont get updated automatically like it happens in 2 way data binding. Hope this helps you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this using JavaScript, since rendering and all interaction with a Plotly plot is done in the browser.  There's a full example (including a CodePen) that's close to what you're trying to do in the Plotly documentation here: https://plot.ly/javascript/zoom-events/

```
var plot = document.getElementById('plot').contentWindow;
var plotTwo = document.getElementById('plotTwo').contentWindow;

document.getElementById('plot').onload = function() {
    pinger = setInterval(function(){
        plot.postMessage({task: 'ping'}, 'https://plot.ly')
    }, 100);
};

window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var message = e.data;
    if(message.pong) {
        console.log('Initial pong, frame is ready to receive');
        clearInterval(pinger);
        // Listening for zoom events, but you can also listen
        // for click and hover by adding them to the array
        plot.postMessage( {
                task: 'listen',
                events: ['zoom']
            }, 'https://plot.ly');
            plotTwo.postMessage({
            task: 'relayout',
            'update': {
                    'xaxis.fixedrange': true,
                    'yaxis.fixedrange': true
                },
        }, 'https://plot.ly');
    }
     else if( message.type == 'zoom' ){
         console.log('zoom', message);
         drawRectangle( message['ranges'] );
     }
    else {
        console.log(message);
    }
});

function drawRectangle( ranges ){
    var rect = {
        'type': 'rect',
        'x0': ranges['x'][0],
        'y0': ranges['y'][0],
        'x1': ranges['x'][1],
        'y1': ranges['y'][1],
        'fillcolor': 'rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.7)',
    }
    plotTwo.postMessage({
        'task': 'relayout',
        'update': { shapes: [rect] },
   }, 'https://plot.ly');
}

function newPlot(){
    var plotURL = document.getElementById('plotURL').value + '.embed';
    var iframe = document.getElementById('plot');
    iframe.src = plotURL;
    var iframeTwo = document.getElementById('plotTwo');
    iframeTwo.src = plotURL;
}
```